# React navigation 5 : Pass arguments with Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am using class components with react navigation5 and I have two classes :

Class DrawerComponent.js

```
export default class DrawerContent extends Component{   
constructor(props){
 super(props);    
}
render(){
 return(
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <DrawerContentScrollView {...this.props}>            
                <Drawer.Section style={styles.drawerSection}>
                    {
                          <DrawerItem 
                                icon={({color,size}) => (
                                 <Icon 
                                 name=""
                                 color={color}
                                 size={size}
                                 />
                                )}
                                label={menu.localizedTitle}
                                onPress = {() =>**{this.props.navigation.navigate("RecordList",{body :'abc' }**)}}/>)
        </Drawer.Section>             
            </View>
        </DrawerContentScrollView>         
    </View>
)}}
```

Now if I have to access value of body in another class, how can I do so?

Comment: I get an error getParam is not a func

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You said react-navigation 5, that works in v4. Ketan's answer is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `RecordList` component, you can access the params with `route`

```js
const RecordList = ({navigation, route})=>{
  const {body} = route.params;
  console.log(body)
}
```

in class based component:

```js
class RecordList extends Component{
  
  render(){
    const {body} = this.props.route.params;
    console.log(body)
    return <View><Text>{body}</Text></View>
  }
}
```

Comment: can u write this in a class component?I dont knw how to write this in class component format. similar to what I have written in the above ex

Comment: in class based component you might have to use ```const {body} = this.props.route.params```

Comment: No, it says cannot read property 'body ' of undefined

Comment: updated. ```const {body} = this.props.route.params```

Comment: working example: https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/passparamsclassbased

Comment: I want to write this code in componentsDidMount and not render, the same thing doesnt work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226988/discussion-between-ketan-ramteke-and-sver).

Comment: Thanks a lot Ketan. After many days, I was able to figure out the issue.!

Comment: Wow, congratulations :)

Answer (score 0):

I am using stackNavigator inside drawerNavigator so I will have to use nested navigation:

```
 this.props.navigation.navigate('RecordList', {screen:'Home',params :{ title: "Home"}})
```

and retrieving can be done exactly like how it is done above in Ketan's answer.